# How are return values of type `impl Trait` borrow-checked?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The following code fails to compile:

```rust
fn foo<'a, F: Fn() -> &'a str>(vec: Vec<i32>, fun: F) -> impl Iterator<Item = i32> {
    println!("{}", fun());
    vec.into_iter()
}

fn main() {
    let s = "hello, world!".to_string();
    let iter = foo(vec![1, 2, 3], || &s);
    drop(s);

    for x in iter {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `s` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:9:10
   |
8  |     let iter = foo(vec![1, 2, 3], || &s);
   |                                   --  - borrow occurs due to use in closure
   |                                   |
   |                                   borrow of `s` occurs here
9  |     drop(s);
   |          ^ move out of `s` occurs here
10 | 
11 |     for x in iter {
   |              ---- borrow later used here
```

It compiles if I replace `foo`'s signature with

```rust
fn foo<'a, F: Fn() -> &'a str>(vec: Vec<i32>, fun: F) -> <Vec<i32> as IntoIterator>::IntoIter {
    // ...
}
```

It makes me believe that `impl Trait` types are borrow-checked more conservatively: the compiler assumes that the returned object captures `fun` even though it doesn't.

However, this interesting example compiles fine:

```rust
fn foo(s: &str) -> impl Iterator<Item = i32> {
    println!("{}", s);
    vec![1, 2, 3].into_iter()
}

fn main() {
    let s = "hello, world!".to_string();
    let iter = foo(&s);
    drop(s);

    for x in iter {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

Here the compiler seems not to assume that the returned `impl Iterator<Item = i32>` borrows `s`.

How exactly are returned `impl Trait` types borrow-checked? When are they assumed to borrow other function arguments, like in the first case? When are they assumed not to, like in the latter case?

Comment: I had expected `-> impl 'static + Iterator<Item=i32>` to make a difference here, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [this issue comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76882#issuecomment-695153572) tells the story here. It sounds like it's an intentional limitation of the type system to be conservative, but I agree with the issue author that this would be good to be able to opt out of:

> The core reason for this behaviour is the variance behaviour of impl Trait in return position: the returned impl Trait is always variant over all generic input parameters, even if not technically used. This is done so that if you change the internal implementation of a public API returning `impl Trait` you don't have to worry about introducing an additional variance param to the API. This could break downstream code and is thus not desireable for Rust's semver system.

Comment: The answer I was looking for: "the returned impl Trait is always variant over all generic input parameters, even if not technically used. This is done so that if you change the internal implementation of a public API returning impl Trait you don't have to worry about introducing an additional variance param to the API"